# Wrap OpenStreetMap at antimeridian using SharpMap

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, sharpmap

I have a simple SharpMap Map object (WinForms) which contains a TileAsyncLayer (OpenStreetMap using BruTile) within the BackgroundLayers collection.

I would like to have the map either wrap at the edges or repeat so that the user can fan continuously east/west without ever reaching the "end" of the map, but there doesn't seem to be a built in option to do this. What would be the simplest way to enable infinite scrolling?

My code:

```
BruTile.Web.HttpTileSource source = KnownTileSources.Create();
TileAsyncLayer background = new TileAsyncLayer(source, "OSM");

mapBox1.Map.BackgroundLayer.Add(background);

mapBox1.Map.ZoomToExtents();
mapBox1.Refresh();
mapBox1.ActiveTool = MapBox.Tools.Pan;
```

Software Versions:

SharpMap: 1.2.0-pre.182830673

BruTile: 2.1.2